# Debug and Hot Reload not working with NativeScript in VS Code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I have just installed NativeScript and the VS Code extension for it, and built a sample 'empty' Vue app [as directed.](https://docs.nativescript.org/development-workflow.html#debugging)
The build worked with no errors (although took a long time!) and the basic app is running on my Android device. But breakpoints don't work , and changes in the .vue files are not being hot-reloaded to the device. The debug console has

> Successfully applied update

whenever i make a change (just a small message text edit) but nothing happens on the device. But I also have this error in the console:

> Error when trying to require webpack.config.js file from path 'C:\Users\quilk\source\repos\NStest\nstest\webpack.config.js'. Error is: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\quilk\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\package.json'

and sure enough, there is no `package.json` at that location.
Running the command `tns doctor` reports no errors.

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449430) but it's 4 years old and maybe things have moved on since then?
I can probably work without hot reload, but debugging with breakponits will be essential.

Answer (score -1):

After searching for a solution I found this https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-vscode-extension/issues/284 and related solution https://github.com/orgs/NativeScript/discussions/9693

Step to solve the problem:

1. add `"sourceMap": true` in tsconfig.json
2. add an empty package.json file in your "AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code" folder
3. add `"sourceMapPathOverrides": {"webpack://app/./*": "$workspaceRoot}/*",}` in your "Attach to .." configuration in launch.json file
4. add `webpack.chainWebpack(config => {config.output.devtoolNamespace('app')})` in your webpack.config.js file

This solved the problem for me.